# Query doesn't show all the results that I need

Tags: mysql

I have the following db table (People):

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  Name  |Building|   Nr   |  Time  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Tim    | House  |   30   |  10:10 |
| Jill   | House  |   31   |  10:20 |
| Tim    | Flat   |   31   |  10:30 |
| NULL   | Tower  |  NULL  |  NULL  |
| Jack   | Hut    |   32   |  10:50 |
| Jane   | Cabin  |   35   |  10:60 |
| Susan  | Cabin  |   35   |  11:70 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Now I want to show all Buildings (and the data that comes with it) that Tim owns. I did that like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `People` WHERE Name="Tim"
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  Name  |Building|   Nr   |  Time  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Tim    | House  |   30   |  10:10 |
| Tim    | Flat   |   31   |  10:30 |
```

So far so good. The thing is, there are more buildings (Tower, Hut and Cabin). I want to show these too but leave the data (accept the building type) blank.

**This result is that I need:**

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  Name  |Building|   Nr   |  Time  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Tim    | House  |   30   |  10:10 |
| Tim    | Flat   |   31   |  10:30 |
| NULL   | Tower  |  NULL  |  NULL  |
| NULL   | Hut    |  NULL  |  NULL  |
| NULL   | Cabin  |  NULL  |  NULL  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Since Tower was already NULL I can easily extract that one using:

```
SELECT * FROM `People` WHERE Name="Tim" OR Name is NULL
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  Name  |Building|   Nr   |  Time  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Tim    | House  |   30   |  10:10 |
| Tim    | Flat   |   31   |  10:30 |
| NULL   | Tower  |  NULL  |  NULL  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Problem is, I still miss the Hut and Cabin. Can this even be done with a query? Also tried some options like GROUP BY etc but this gave mixed data in return. Also searched using Google but had no luck.

Hope anyone can help me out!

ps. as a workaround I can add in the db:

```
 | NULL   | Hut    |  NULL  |  NULL  |
 | NULL   | Cabin  |  NULL  |  NULL  |
```

But that will be a immense job to contain this table when you add more buildings

Comment: I tested this, and it's look like that everything is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
select * from people where Name = 'Tim' 
union 
select 'NULL', Building, NULL, NULL from   people where Name != 'Tim';
```

Can do what you want ?

Answer (score 2):

Your table does not show Tim owning the (Tower, Hut, Cabin) otherwise it would show in the first query you posted.  The database is giving you the correct information in the beginning.  If Tim is meant to own the other types of structures the data needs to reflect it.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by thinking about your query; you are asking the database two questions:

1) Show me all the building types that Tim owns

2) Show me all the building types that Tim doesn't own.

The simplest way to do this is a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) query:

```
SELECT Name, Building, Nr, Time FROM People WHERE Name = 'Tim'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT NULL, Building, NULL, NULL FROM People WHERE Building NOT IN (SELECT Building FROM People WHERE Name = 'Tim')
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: Works great, though using @Gianluca solution (which does the same, but is smaller). I will take a look at that Union function, never used it before. Also to all others that gave suggestions: thanks

Answer (score 0):

Really strange, are you sure you have not any GROUP BY Nr or Time? Try using a escaped query:

```
SELECT * FROM `People` WHERE `Name`="Tim" OR `Name` is NULL OR `Name`='NULL' OR `NAME`=''
```

May be you have the string NULL instead of the real NULL. Just a hint, try to use always lowercase in fields name in dbs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(Name='Tim',Name,NULL) AS Name,
       Building,
       IF(Name='Tim',Nr,NULL) AS Nr,
       IF(Name='Tim',Time,NULL) AS Time
FROM People ;
```

This should give your desired result.